# Clear cache in Mule

Tags: java, mule

I have an application where xml messages are generated from the Mule flows and forwarded to a JMS queue. But the flow does not run correctly until a step by step debug is done. What causes this? Is there an in-memory cache in Mule? If so, is there a way to clear it? Help, please!

Comment: any code? any error messages?

Comment: nope, no errors, no exceptions. The message just goes to the dead letter queue.

Comment: Have you checked the flow is enabled?

Comment: The flow works correctly now that I have debugged it. Before that all messages were dumped to the dead letter queue, without any errors. Is there a reason behind this?